# attempt to call a nil value (field 'Draw3DText')

Tags: lua, fivem

i have this "function" in cl_main.lua:

```
Citizen.CreateThread(function()
   for i = 1, #Config.SpecialStores do
      local Blip = AddBlipForCoord(Config.SpecialStores[i].Coords);
      SetBlipSprite (Blip, Config.SpecialStores[i].Blip[1]);
      SetBlipDisplay(Blip, 4);
      SetBlipScale  (Blip, Config.SpecialStores[i].Blip[3]);
      SetBlipColour (Blip, Config.SpecialStores[i].Blip[2]);
      SetBlipAsShortRange(Blip, true);
      BeginTextCommandSetBlipName('STRING');
      AddTextComponentString(Config.SpecialStores[i].Label);
      EndTextCommandSetBlipName(Blip)       
   end
   while true do
      local sleepThread, Player = 1500, PlayerPedId();
      while not Stores.Interiors do
         Citizen.Wait(100)
      end
      if (GetInteriorFromEntity(Player) ~= 0) then
         for _, Data in pairs(Stores.Interiors) do
            if (GetInteriorFromEntity(Player) == Data.InteriorId) then
               sleepThread = 5;
               local Dst = #(GetEntityCoords(Player) - Data.Checkout);
               if Dst < 15.0 then
                  Utils.Draw3DText(Data.Checkout,'~g~E~w~ ');
                  if Dst < 1.0 and IsControlJustReleased(0, 38) then
                     Stores.OpenStore()
                  end
               end
               if IsPedArmed(Player, 7) and Data.Robbable then
                  if IsPlayerFreeAiming(PlayerId()) then
                     local Retval, Entity = GetEntityPlayerIsFreeAimingAt(PlayerId());
                     if Retval and GetEntityModel(Entity) == GetHashKey('mp_m_shopkeep_01') then
                        Stores.StartRobbing({
                           InteriorId = Data.InteriorId,
                           Cashier = Entity
                        })
                     end
                  else
                     local Retval, Entity = GetPlayerTargetEntity(PlayerId());
                     if Retval and GetEntityModel(Entity) == GetHashKey('mp_m_shopkeep_01') then
                        Stores.StartRobbing({
                           InteriorId = Data.InteriorId,
                           Cashier = Entity
                        })
                     end
                  end
               end
            end
         end
      end
```

And then i get back in f8 "attempt to call a nil value (field 'Draw3DText')"
I have tried to make on the top like "Utils = {}" since i understand ish that its the "utils" that return a nil. Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try `ESX.Game.Utils.DrawText3D`

Comment: Dosent work either

Comment: well you're attempting to call a nil value. we cannot help you with that. what made you think you could call this? where did you get this from?  you did not even bother to share what API you're using and which reference manual you're referring to. add more details please. provide some links.